# How to get a RGB color scale in Chroma.js

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

I'm using the [Chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) library to generate a color scale.

So far I'm using this to generate 25 'rainbow' colors:

```
var scale = chroma.scale(['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple']).colors(25);
```

But when I log each color:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
   console.log(scale[i]);
}
```

The color is a HEX color like **#ff0000**, how do I get it to be **RGB**?

Answer (score 1):

Just recall chroma on the returned value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
   console.log(chroma(scale[i]).rgb());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a function for converting a hex color to a rgb color:

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}

alert( hexToRgb("#0033ff").g ); // "51";
```

This is taken from Tim Down's answer here, where you can also find a lot more about hex to rgb color conversion:

[RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)